# Throwing exception in SQL MERGE clause is not possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

I want to merge 2 tables only if all of the IDs in the source table exist in the target table.
But it is not possible to throw exceptions inside merge clause.
What are my alternative options to achieve the same result?

I tried this:

```
MERGE [dbo].[Target] as tgt
USING [dbo].[Source] as src
ON (tgt.ID = src.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET tgt.Name = src.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    THROW 51000, 'error: not all ids match!', 1;
```

I expected it to update the target table only if the source table has all the IDs there are in the target table but instead, I got an error saying:

> Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'. Expecting DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, `THROW` isn't a valid DML operation; your options are `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. Why use a `MERGE` here at all if you only want to `UPDATE`? Just use an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Not to mention your syntax for [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is incorrect too.

Comment: If you want to check if all the rows match, you would be better off with a `(NOT) EXISTS` in an `IF` to `THROW` your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use arbitrary statements in the `THEN` part of a `MERGE`, [the syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is quite specific about what you are allowed to do.

If you want to `THROW` on such rows then just use a `IF EXISTS... WHERE NOT EXISTS`. And then convert the `MERGE` into a normal joined `UPDATE`.

Since it's now two statements, you are going to need an explicit transaction and locking hints.

```sql
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Source as src WITH (SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.Target as tgt WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
        WHERE tgt.ID = src.ID
    )
)
    THROW 50001, N'error: not all ids match!', 1;


UPDATE tgt
SET Name = src.Name
FROM dbo.Target as tgt
JOIN dbo.Source as src ON tgt.ID = src.ID;

COMMIT;
```

If you want the error message to tell you the first ID that fails, you could store it in a variable then check that variable for `NULL`.

```sql
DECLARE @message nvarchar(1000);

SELECT TOP (1)
  @message =  CONCAT(N'error: id ', src.ID, N' is not in target')
FROM dbo.Source as src WITH (SERIALIZABLE)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Target as tgt WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE tgt.ID = src.ID
);

IF @message IS NOT NULL
    THROW 50001, @message, 1;
```

Comment: That works great, can you explain a bit how and why the IF EXISTS works here and why do you need the "SERIALIZABLE" and "UPDLOCK" statements, it is a bit unclear to me, thanks

Comment: and is there a way to find the first id was not in the target table? so the error will be like 'error: id @id is not in target'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14264674/14868997. And see edit